# Getting Error: API key and the authentication credentials are from different projects while registering Beacon on Google Proximity Beacon API

Tags: google-beacon-platform

While registering the beacon using Google proximity beacon API like this, https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErgeB.png.

I am getting **Error: 403: Permission_denied** https://i.stack.imgur.com/OILrm.png.

On the right top corner there is a gear logo when i passed my API key and OAuth 2.0 Client ID from Credential page of my google development console 
,https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2k3R.png into https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdBzt.png, i got following error:https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbetJ.png

How to remove this **ERROR: API key and the authentication credentials are from different projects?**

Please also explain me the way to generate UID which is required in the id parameter while registering beacons as i have got few links but they all need Mac, How to generate UID in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

The only method in the Beacon API that supports API keys is [getForObserved](https://developers.google.com/beacons/proximity/reference/rest/v1beta1/beaconinfo/getforobserved). All other portions of the API only support authentication using your OAuth 2.0 Client ID. I would recommend following the steps in the [Authorize and Authenticate Requests](https://developers.google.com/beacons/proximity/how-tos/authorizing) guide. This guide covers all the basics of creating credentials to get you into the API. You can get started using the OAuth Playground.

One other note: The OAuth Playground will required a **WEB** client ID, not the one you currently have created for Android. Once you get beyond that stage, [here is an article](https://newcircle.com/s/post/1755/2015/08/31/google-proximity-beacons---part-1) I wrote that will explain the basics of using the management side of the API in an Android application.

Comment: Hi @Devunwired ,I have been following Authorize and Authenticate Requests guide for couple of days, but still i am getting the same error **API key and the authentication credentials are from different projects**. As I am new to google developer console, maybe I am missing some key step during OAuth2.0 Authentication Credentials,While generating SHA1 fingerprint I am getting the Creation date: Jan 5, 2015, as well as the debug.keystore file is not getting updated.Is that an issue ? I have imported your proximity-manager-master app in android studio.

Comment: ,Sir Please help me out. I am all gone stuck at this point only.

Comment: Well, let's start with the obvious question: Are your API key and your OAuth Client ID defined in two separate console projects? Because they cannot be. All your proximity beacon credentials must be defined in the same console project where the Proximity Beacon API is enabled.